# Arduino GSM Modem GPRS Communication to a server

Tags: arduino, gprs

I have Arduino board with SIM900A GSM Modem setup. My requirement is to connect to a server and send / receive information.

My server would be placed in some remote place and would probably not be in a network. It would have LAMP setup (Linux, Apache, MySQL and Python). I mean its just a standalone server and one cannot access it via Internet. However it would have an IP of its own.

So is it that using this GSM Modem at Arduino side only I can connect to my server OR do I need a GSM Modem setup my web server side also - if in case I need it at my web server site then what AT commands set I need to follow. Is there any extra other setup I need to make.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at doing a similar thing with the Arduino GSM shield 
( http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield )
I believe the shield can be connected to a computer with the appropriate software installed - like - ( http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/index.php?p= ) - without using an Arduino board to interface.

The GSM shield will need to have an RS232 interface added and connected to the appropriate pins for RX/TX and appropriate power supplied. Connection between the two will then be a standard RS232 cable. The software mentioned above (smstools) can send the appropriate commands directly to the GSM board.

The Arduino board GSM / combination is mainly ONLY if you want to play with GSM modem with small projects yourself.

The modem is a fully capable stand alone device that is capable of responding directly to the right commands (hence an application like smstools).